# Why does this logo not have blurry edges even when zoomed?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, designers, pixel

The logo at bottom don't have much blurry edges. All horizontal and vertical lines are crisp, even when zoomed 200%. (You can try it after opening in MS Paint or Windows photo viewer and similar options on any other OS).

One the other hand, most of horizontal and vertical lines of 1st logo are blurred even when not zoomed.

I designed 1st one. My friend designed 2nd one to show that *his* edges are sharp unlike mine. He combined both in a single file and sent me for comparison.

Why is this different?

EDIT: My friend designed and exported this in PowerPoint.

[image]

Comment: How are they exported (which file type)? And where do you place/use them to discover the difference?

Comment: @Wolff the difference is everywhere. On whatsapp, on any chat on emails, on Windows photo viewer.

Comment: Both are in same file. Exported as PNG.

Comment: Can someone please point out the problem in this question? I would like to make it better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that the anchor points of your friend's logo follows the pixel grid:

[image]

And that the anchor points of your logo doesn't and has decimal coordinates:

[image]

If the contours of your vector shapes lies between the pixel grid, anti-aliasing will be introduced.

Comment: I didn't see your second question about this subject posted minutes after this one. I think this answer also answers the other question. Do you agree?

Comment: You added the information about the second logo being exported from PowerPoint after I posted my answer. Have you examined the PowerPoint file yourself to see if the logo indeed follows the pixel grid?

Comment: I don't know if PowerPoint have pixel grid.

Comment: I guess 2nd quetion can have different explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Your file has rounded corners.. his file does not.

Therefore his file can be more "pixel perfect", especially for the S, your file will *always* have anti-aliasing.

Comment: Okay. But let's ignore those rounded corners. The horizontal and vertical lines are main thing.

Comment: You **can't** "ignore rounded corners". The corners introduce a level of anti-aliasing and in order for the horizontals and verticals to appear to align with the corners properly *they* will *also* be anti-aliased to a degree. You asked "why" and  the **rounded corners are *why***.

Comment: is it also true even when I follow align to pixel grid and give corner radius? I would doubt that.

Comment: I'm not going to argue the matter. **I know** why. But you are free to explore things for yourself.

Comment: not arguing :) It's just I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, perhaps, before posting that I'm wrong, maybe try exploring the issue??? Remove the rounded corners and see if it exports sharper perhaps.

Comment: sure I'll try that.

Comment: I tried and unfortunately it made no difference. They had similar blurry edges. If you want I share open file of the same.

Comment: @Scott has a good point there. You can export with *anti-aliasing* set to *none*, but that will remove anti-aliasing from rounded corners and diagonal lines and look jagged. How should Illustrator be able to not anti-alias horizontal and vertical lines (and thereby move them a little bit to fit the pixel grid) while still have smooth rounded corners? It would distort the shape in unexpected ways.